# scala convert List of map to map

Tags: scala

I have a simple question

I have List of Map like this

```
List(
      Map("a" -> "a"),
      Map("b" -> "b")
    )
```

And I want the result like this

```
Map(
  "a"->"a",
  "b"->"b"
)
```

It can be overwrite if the key is duplication 
Any one please help me

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can combine `flatten` and `toMap`:

```scala
val list = List(Map("k1" -> "v1", "k2" -> "v2"))
list.flatten.toMap // Map(k1 -> v1, k2 -> v2)
```

`flatten` will convert the list of maps into a list of tuples and then `toMap` will convert your list of tuples into a map.

Comment: Are you sure? Just make sure at least the key has the same type in all maps - for example you must have only Map[String, String] instances.

Comment: Otherwise indeed it does not compile.

Comment: Why is this a right answer ? Question was transform List( Map, Map) and not List(Map) to Map. This isn't even working on Scastie. Take the list from the question and try to do it with l.flatten you will receive an error.

Comment: Ok it compiles. I was receiving Java Maps from a Java library which I am using. This caused the error. Sorry.

Answer (score 7):

You can try using reduce:

```
scala> val list = List(Map("k1" -> "v1", "k2" -> "v2"))
list: List[scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,String]] = List(Map(k1 -> v1, k2 -> v2))

scala> list.reduce(_ ++ _)
res0: scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,String] = Map(k1 -> v1, k2 -> v2)

scala> val list = List(Map("k1" -> "v1"), Map("k2" -> "v2"))
list: List[scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,String]] = List(Map(k1 -> v1), Map(k2 -> v2))

scala> list.reduce(_ ++ _)
res1: scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,String] = Map(k1 -> v1, k2 -> v2)
```

This way you needn't convert to any intermediate data type.